# Etimología de "paleto"

Tags: etimología

El DLE define [**paleto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RXwfhgn) como

> 1. adj. despect. Poco educado y de modales y gustos poco refinados. U. m. c. s.
> 2. adj. despect. Dicho de una persona: Rústica y sin habilidad para desenvolverse en ambientes urbanos. U. m. c. s.
> 3. adj. despect. Propio o característico de la persona paleta.
> 4. m. gamo.

y recoge que procede de ***paleta***. Por otro lado, [**paleta**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RXmCtRy) es

> 1. f. Tabla pequeña con un agujero en uno de sus extremos por donde el pintor mete el dedo pulgar y sobre la que tiene ordenados los colores.
> 2. f. Conjunto o variedad de colores usados habitualmente por un pintor. La paleta de Goya.
> 3. f. Instrumento de hierro o acero inoxidable compuesto por un platillo redondo con agujeros y un astil largo, que se emplea en la cocina, principalmente para sacar los fritos de la sartén.
> 4. f. Badil u otro instrumento semejante con que se remueve la lumbre.
> 5. f. Utensilio de palastro, de forma triangular y mango de madera, que usan los albañiles para manejar la mezcla o mortero.
> 6. f. Omóplato, paletilla.
> 7. f. pala (‖ diente incisivo).
> 8. f. Cada una de las tablas de madera o planchas metálicas, planas o curvas, que se fijan sobre una rueda o eje para que ellas mismas
>    muevan algo o para ser movidas por el agua, el viento u otra fuerza.
> 9. f. Taurom. Parte anterior externa del asta del toro.
> 10. f. Am. En algunos juegos de pelota, pala de madera.
> 11. f. Col., C. Rica, El Salv., Guat., Méx., Nic., Perú, P. Rico y R. Dom. polo (‖ helado).
> 12. f. coloq. Ur. Persona que acompaña a una pareja como carabina.

¿De cuál de todas esas acepciones de ***paleta*** procede **paleto**?

**Edición**

En el Diccionario de Autoridades de la R.A.E. se recoge como acepción principal de **paleto** "el gamo que tiene hastas, y los ramos dellas anchos, de hechura de palas: por cuya razón se le dió este nombre.", y una segunda entrada "Por alusión llaman al hombre rústico, zafio y de las Aldéas". lo que parece sugerir que proviene de **pala** más que de **paleta**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que indica el diccionario etimológico de Corominas es más rebuscado que lo que dice @Diego, yo mismo no lo comprendo muy bien en realidad, pero hay que tener en cuenta que esta fuente es las más confiables que hay.

Según Corominas, a las astas de los ciervos gamos se les dice "paletas" por su forma de palas. (Puedo confirmar que la misma metáfora se hace en Chile con respecto a las ramas de los cactus nopales o *tunas*, a los que también llamamos *paletas*, y parecen efectivamente astas).

Por extensión, al gamo se les llama *paleto*, como se ve en la cuarta acepción del diccionario de la RAE.

De ahí, documentado desde 1737, *paleto* también significa "rústico", "zafio". Es decir, parece darse una relación entre el animal silvestre y lo "poco refinado".

Answer (score 1):

[Etimologías de Chile](http://etimologias.dechile.net/?paleto) propone que es una *metonimia* (designar a una cosa por el nombre de otra, tomando el efecto por la causa o viceversa) que reduce al ser humano a un instrumento que utiliza (un palo o una pala).

Así, `paleto` habría empezado a usarse para referirse a un labrador y luego de forma más genérica a gente rústica poco instruida o sofisticada.

De las acepciones dadas para "paleta", entiendo que la que mejor recoge esta teoría sería la séptima (pala).

Comment: Quizá la que indica la RAE si lo entendemos como la séptima acepción, o quizá proviene de otros términos como "palo".

Answer (score 0):

En términos coloquiales (España), se llama "paleta" a personas que trabajan en el sector de la construcción.

Por lo tanto, yo siempre he asociado "ser un paleto" a las connotaciones negativas que puede tener alguien que trabaja en sectores de baja cualificación: básicamente, con poca cultura, pocos modales...

Por eso, se ajusta más a la quinta (5) definición de "paleta" que has dejado en la descripción de la pregunta.

Comment: Interesante. Puede ser que se refiera a un palé (de lo que sea) o a personas que usan una trans**paleta** para llevar carga en el trabajo? Sería como decir "este es el gruísta, este el (trans)paleta, este el ..."

Comment: No, no! no un palé, sino una paleta o paletilla, que es una herramienta que usan los albañiles para fijar cemento y cosas así (no sé mucho del oficio, disculpa!)